# JUnit 5 -- how to make test execution dependent on another test passing?

Tags: junit, junit5

Student here.  In JUnit 5, what is the best way to implement conditional test execution based on whether another test succeeded or failed?  I presume it would involve [ExecutionCondition](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ExecutionCondition.html), but I am unsure how to proceed.  Is there a way to do this without having to add my own state to the test class?

To note, I am aware of [dependent assertions](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-assertions), but I have multiple [nested tests](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-nested) that represent distinct substates, and so I would like a way to do this at the test level itself.

Example:

```java
@Test
void testFooBarPrecondition() { ... }

// only execute if testFooBarPrecondition succeeds
@Nested
class FooCase { ... }

// only execute if testFooBarPrecondition succeeds    
@Nested
class BarCase { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

> @Nested tests give the test writer more capabilities to express the
> relationship among several groups of tests. Such nested tests make use
> of Java’s nested classes and facilitate hierarchical thinking about
> the test structure. Here’s an elaborate example, both as source code
> and as a screenshot of the execution within an IDE.

As stated from `JUnit 5` documentation, `@Nested` is use for convenient display in your IDE. I would rather use [Assumptions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-assumptions) for your preconditions inside a [Depentent Assertions](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-assertions).

```
assertAll(
            () -> assertAll(
                    () -> assumeTrue(Boolean.FALSE)
            ),

            () -> assertAll(
                    () -> assertEquals(10, 4 + 6)
            )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the problem by extracting common precondition logic in a @BeforeEach/@BeforeAll setup method, then use [assumptions](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-assumptions), which was developed exactly for the purpose of condition test execution. Some sample code:

```java
class SomeTest {

    @Nested
    class NestedOne {
        @BeforeEach
        void setUp() {
            boolean preconditionsMet = false;
            //precondition code goes here

            assumeTrue(preconditionsMet);
        }

        @Test // not executed when precodition is not met
        void aTestMethod() {}
    }

    @Nested
    class NestedTwo {
        @Test // executed
        void anotherTestMethod() { }
    }
}
```

Comment: When giving advice to adhere to Java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase. Always.

Comment: Is the ordering of test executions in JUnit5 well-defined?

Comment: @Henrik there is no support for ordered test execution in JUnit5 yet. They use reflection to find the method names and since Java 7 the order of methods returned by reflection is not defined. I believe they are considering adding some kind of support in the future, as I followed the project and this was dropped from 5.0.0 release.

Comment: @Kotse: Ok, thanks. Isn't it a problem with the proposed solution then? How can we be dependent on the success of another test if we can't ensure that it's executed before our test?

Comment: @Henrik Since we cannot depend on success/fail from another test, the proposed solution is to move the code in a place where we can depend to be executed before tests. `@BeforeEach` will guarantee this code will be executed before tests found in NestedOne class. Then `assumeThat()` will handle the conditional execution

Comment: Support of Junit test ordering will be delivered in Junit 5.4